# pandas groupby apply function that take N-column frame and returns object

Tags: python, pandas

Is there a 'transform' method of something like that to apply a function to groups (all columns at once) and return an object? Anything I try seems to return one object per column in the group.

For example consider the data

```
               Maturity                Date      s  Term  Month
0   2012-02-01 00:00:00 2012-01-03 00:00:00  2.993    29      2
18  2012-03-01 00:00:00 2012-01-03 00:00:00  3.022    58      3
57  2012-04-01 00:00:00 2012-01-03 00:00:00  3.084    89      4
117 2012-05-01 00:00:00 2012-01-03 00:00:00  3.138   119      5
...
```

and suppose I do a groupby on Date and apply some function to the groups labeled by (Term, Month, s). The result should be something like

```
               Maturity                result
2012-02-01 00:00:00 2012-01-03         object
2012-03-01 00:00:00 2012-01-03         object
2012-04-01 00:00:00 2012-01-03         object
....
```

I can obviously just iterate through the groups and aggregate the results but I imagine I'm just missing something obvious about how to use one of the transform methods.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could apply the function and then aggregate each group manually. For example, assuming the aggregation is a mean and the function is the sum of the column, you could:

```
df.groupby("Date")['Term', 'Month', 's'].apply(lambda rows: np.mean(rows['Term'] + rows['Month'] + rows['s']))
```

So if we assume a `fit` method that builds some model from a dataframe having the columns "month", "Term" and "s":

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np 

def fit (dataframe):
    return {  "param1": np.mean(dataframe["Term"]) + np.max(dataframe["month"]), "param2": np.std(dataframe["s"])}
```

And a dataframe containing those colummns for a bunch of dates:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"date":  ["20140101", "20140202", "20140203"] * 4, "Term" : np.random.randint(100, size=12),"month": np.random.randint(12, size=12),"s": np.random.rand(12)*3})
print df
```

(outputs: )

```
    Term      date  month         s
0     24  20140101      6  2.364798
1     43  20140202      9  0.066188
2     59  20140203      6  1.078052
3     40  20140101      3  1.982825
4     34  20140202      4  2.089518
5     20  20140203      1  2.412956
6     84  20140101      8  0.779843
7     62  20140202      9  0.918860
8     32  20140203     11  2.613289
9     16  20140101      9  0.788347
10    23  20140202      6  0.982986
11    27  20140203      1  0.658260
```

Then we can apply the fit() on all the columns at once for each group of rows:

```
modelPerDate = df.groupby("date").apply(fit)
print modelPerDate
```

Which produces a dataframe of models, one per date:

```
date
20140101    {'param2': 0.70786647858131047, 'param1': 50.0}
20140202    {'param2': 0.71852297283637756, 'param1': 49.5}
20140203    {'param2': 0.83876295773013798, 'param1': 45.5}
```

Comment: It is a function like 'fit'. There is not easy decomposition like '+'.

Comment: the argument received in apply() is a dataframe, containing the rows of one group and the columns selected by ['Term', 'Month', 's'], is it possible to run your fit method on that? You should then obtain one fitted "object" per date.
The "+" in my example is adding the columns, then the mean is aggregating the resulting list as a single result.

Comment: I should have mentioned that I can use the 'apply' or 'agg' function but it returns the same (redundant) object for each column. So it appears that my function is receiving access to the full group each time (which is what I want) but that it is being called once for each column in the group (or at least that's how the result is populated).

Comment: Hmmm, I think you are correct for the usage of `agg`, but the `apply` method should normally receive all the columns at once for each group. I edited my answer above to illustrate that.